# Dynamically opening multiple tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm using bootstrap and jQuery to control tabs dynamically on my website. Until now each button was targeting only one element, but I want to target multiple.

Here's a bit of my code:

```
<!-- Dynamic Tabs controller -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav-tabs a").click(function() {
    $(this).tab('show');
  });
});
</script>

<!-- Navigation Tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#staff"> 
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#tech">
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Elements to show -->
<div id="staff" class="tab-pane fade"></div>
<div id="tech" class="tab-pane fade"></div>
```

Now how do I open both staff and tech by pressing on single navigation tab ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I managed to solve this on my own. I will post an answer to help others looking for the same solution.

The trick was to use **data-target**.

Here's the modified code:

```
<!-- Navigation Tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#staff" data-target="#staff, #tech"> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now when I click on the staff button, both staff and tech tabs are opening.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
$(this).tab('show');
```

To:

```
$("#staff, #tech").tab('show');
```

You can learn about the concept of `this` in JavaScript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), get documentation for that [boostrap function here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) (scroll to tabs), and learn about jQuery's [multiple selector syntax here](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/), which is a comma separated list of selectors.

Comment: To shorten the code I've shown only 2 tabs as an example. There are more tabs in my code than those 2. In different cases I want my tabs to select either one or multiple elements.

Comment: @KoKsMAN If you have different triggers for different groups, you need a different click function for each, or some logic to determine which group it belongs to within your existing click function. Share your entire code in a jsfiddle and note what goes together and I can advise.